# What does David Mitchell say here?

Tags: spoken-english

What does David Mitchell say here?

I hear

> To remind me why a lot of other people don't watch mikes television.

[Did a horse break David Mitchell's selfie stick? - Would I Lie To You: Series 11 Episode 5 - BBC One (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/Fn9xnLaA0u0?t=186)

Comment: It's terribly slurred in the few syllables after **remind**, even at 50% speed, but it's clearly "much", as Joel said, not "mikes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He actually says:

> To remind me why a lot of other people don't watch ***much*** television

In response to the previous comedian saying 'that reminds me why I don't watch much theatre' as the acting between David Mitchel and Rob Brydon was purposefully awful for comedic effect. David Mitchel is poking fun at the fact people like him and the others are actually on television and they're all terrible (which we all know they are not!)

Good job in watching some quality comedy TV though, if you haven't watched it already - watch 'Peep Show'.

Comment: Your transcription makes perfect sense, but what I hear sounds more like this: **To remind me a lot of other people why they don't watch much television.** I know that doesn't sound like good English, but that's just what I hear.

Comment: Yes I should say I didn't write either quote verbatim. I simply listened once and paraphrased - listening again he does stumble his words at the beginning for sure. Likely due to his excitement in the pun itself.